# AWS Amplify push keeps failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, npm, aws-amplify

I am playing around with AWS Amplify for Flutter. I created a Graph QL API locally but when I try to push using `amplify push`, it fails with below error. I have tried updating npm as well cleared npm cache.

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/Users/naman/.Trash'
An error occurred during the push operation: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/Users/naman/.Trash'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out iTerm didn't have Full Disk access. You can change this via "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access". Unlock, click '+' and then select the terminal you're using to run Amplify CLI. You'd have to restart Terminal program.

Comment: Thank you! This was also the fix for `amplify pull` for me. (amplify version 8.0.2)